# How do I add another domain but not to the public_html folder in cpanel?

Tags: cpanel, multiple-domains

When I try to add another domain to the account the public_html folder is already grayed out near the document root input. how can I put the domain as a sibling folder to the public_html folder?

[image: What I see]

So I will have 2 domains like this

```
1st domain - *root*/public_html/

2nd domain - *root*/anotherdomain.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guy named cPanelRex from another place answered my question.
I need to enable something from the higher-level account:

WHM >> Tweak Settings by the "Restrict document roots to public_html" toggle. https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/server-configuration/tweak-settings/#domains

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as Addon domain.
In previous versions of Cpanel, the Addon domains had a separate tab underneath Domains tab, but in current versions all the domains are gathered in one place.

1. Click "Domains" under the "Domains" section.
2. Click the "Create A New Domain" button.
3. Enter the domain name to add in the "Domain" text box.
4. Deselect the "Share document root (/home/username/public_html) with “domain.tld”." option.
5. Enter the directory where you want the files for this domain to exist.
6. Click the "Submit" button.

Useful screenshot [here](https://nescom.co.ke/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/create-addon-domain.png)

Comment: Unlike the screenshot, where there's the house icon, I see public_html already written, so every location I will write will start with "public_html/" but I don't want that. I want to add the domain to the previous folder. how do I do that? I know it's possible

Comment: I added a picture to the original question that might explain

Comment: Are you renting this cpanel access ?  Because you might be renting a "shared server" which doesn't give you full control.  But if it is hosted, and you are paying less than 10 bucks a month, I'm going to bet you don't have access to do what you want.

Comment: Your Cpanel account settings doesn't allow you to create a domain folder outside the public_html . As @easleyfixed said, if you are using a shared hosting , your cpanel may have limitations.

Comment: I have access to the higher-level account, so I figure out what I need to enable in order to allow myself this option. I consider this as answered.